# A function that maps from A to its power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a non empty set and $f: A \to P(A)$ some function.$P(A)$ is the set of all the subsets of the set $A$. I have to show that $Z_{f} := \{x \in A | x \not\in f(x)\}$ is not in the image of $f$.

I have no idea how to do this, please help. I guess showing that $f$ is not surjective would be one way, since that means it won't take the whole image space but further than that I don't understand..

Thank you in advance

Comment: I meant to say exactly the opposite! I'm gonna edit it now.

Comment: are you aware of [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)?

Comment: It follows easily from Cantor's theorem that $f$ is not surjective. Since the cardinality of the image space is bigger than that of the definition space.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Suppose $Z_f$ is in the image of $f$. Then there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = Z_f$. Now look for a contradiction by thinking about whether or not $a$ is a member of $Z_f$.

You should probably change "The" in the title of your question to "A".

Comment: Why we defined $Z_{f}$ in this way exactly ..... is there an intuition behind this definition?

Comment: @Intuition The intuition is that self-reference can cause interesting things to happen. It led Cantor to his argument about the set of subsets of a set, and  Russell to Russell's paradox:  the "set of sets that aren't members of themselves" can't be a set. And no one can shave the barber who shaves everyone who doesn't shave himself. And the old paradox "this sentence is false", which can be neither true nor false.

Comment: I think this is a philosophical answer rather than an answer related to $Z_{f}$ ... anyway thank you :)

Comment: @Intuition I think philosophical musings like those -  part of a mathematician's intuition  - would naturally lead him or her to think about $Z_f$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $Z_f$ is the set of all elements $x$ such that $x \notin f(x)$.
2. If $Z_f$ were the image of some point $z\in A$, this means that there is a $z$ such that $f(z) = Z_f$.
3. Now we can find a contradiction by asking whether $z\in Z_f$ or $z\notin Z_f$.
4. If $z\in Z_f$, then by definition of $Z_f$, we must have $z\notin f(z)$. But $f(z)=Z_f$, a contradiction.

   If $z\notin Z_f$, then by definition of $Z_f$, we must have $z\in f(z)$. But $f(z) = Z_f$, a contradiction.
5. Since every outcome results in a contradiction, such a $z$ cannot exist. Hence $Z_f$ is not the image of any point in $A$.