# Diagonal set definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider surjection

$f: N \rightarrow P,$ where $P$ is the power set of $N$.  Define set $D$, subset of $N,$ such that for all $n,$ $n$ is element of $D$ iff $n$ is not element of $f(n).$  Questions:

1. Is D a "legal" set within the restrictions of set theory?
2. What is an example of D?

Many thanks for any help, Agapito

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's perfectly legal. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391576/a-function-that-maps-from-a-to-its-power-set/

Comment: By the way, this is on the way to proving that $f$ cannot be a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

The definition
$$ D = \{ n\in N \mid n \notin f(n) \} $$
is perfectly valid in standard set theory -- that is, set theory based on the ZFC axioms. The *Axiom of Separation* (also known as the axiom of Specification or Subsets) guarantees that this expression describes a set that exists, whenever $N$ and $f$ exist.

There are non-mainstream set theories where this is not allowed -- in particular in NF set theory, the formula $n\notin f(n)$ is not allowed to appear inside a set builder, because it is not "stratified" (even though the formula is considered to be meaningful in itself).

But this is not something you need to worry about in ordinary mathematics, since that is always supposed to be formalizable in ZFC, rather than NF.

---

Examples: If $f$ is the function that maps every $n$ to $\{n\}$ then $D$ becomes the empty set. On the other hand, if $f$ is the function that maps everything to $\varnothing$, then $D$ becomes all of $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  AM